# Sql Server Database Mail attachments from FileTable msg 22015 (file is invalid)

Tags: sql-server, database-mail, filetable

I'm transitioning email services in an web (mvc3) application from .Net to sql Database Mail. Some of the content we want to send as attachments has been uploaded to a sql FileTable. When I use the UNC path for the attachment (@file_attachments=), I get this error:

```
Msg 22051, Level 16, State 1, Line 0 Attachment file
\\computername\mssqlserver\foldername\foldername\DE107D2C-B945-4F1E-A4B9-4B398C9DE758.jpg)
is invalid.
```

I can open the file directly using the same path, and when I copy the file to a local folder, the file attaches fine. I suspect that the issue is folder permission for the FileTable directory. But I can't find any hooks to set the rights for that folder.

I'm running the EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail locally in SSMS (local sql instance) using windows authentication.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior was validated in the Microsoft Database Engine forum and I submitted feedback: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/756716/sql-server-database-mail-attachments-from-filetable-msg-22051-file-is-invalid

Note that the error code I had in this title should be 22051 and not 22015.

In the mean time, I'm using a work around of copying the files using the sql command shell to another local folder, and using that path for the attachment

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

share your attachement folder  to Network service user in which attchment file exist.
and give attachemnt file path like \\ip_addres\filefolder\abc.pdf to send_dbmail stored procedure.
This will work if file and sql server are on different machines